# Mixing Terminal Services and VMware View

Tags: terminal-server, vmware-view

we are in the process of evaluating VMware View 4.5 and I have a question about integrating it into the Terminal Services environment that is already in place.

Can the VMware View Connection Broker serve as a connection broker for TS farms with a TS session director running at the same time? Is it best to choose one broker over another? Can the TS Director function as a broker for View Desktops (I don't think so, but worth asking)?

If we chose VMware's broker, what objections do you think our TS farm administrators might have? Do you have to put the View Agent on each TS server?

We already have a decent sized deployment of TS (3 farms, up to 4 servers each) and a Terminal Services Session Director but some of our use cases are requiring VMware View for CAD software, etc. - I'd like to be able to integrate the two if at all possible.

What about licensing issues? Would you have to double purchase View/TS licenses in this case?

[cross posted on VMware Communities](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/285659)

Comment: Out of curiosity - have you/are you also considering XenDesktop?

Comment: @Clint: We are not evaluating XenDesktop.  Does XenDesktop offer TS integration?

Comment: XenDesktop includes Citrix XenApp, which is built on top of TS.  I would suggest you take a look (it does work w/ vmware as the underlaying hypervisor). www.citrix.com/xendesktop

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Quest vWorkspace also... Cheaper and more powerfull that XenDesktop.

Comment: In what ways is vWorkspace more powerfull than XenDesktop?